# How to find the order of G using the size of G and its complement

Tags: discrete-mathematics, computer-science

If the size of graph G is 19 and the size of its complement G-bar is 17 then find the order of G?

Answer (score 1):

So the complete graph over the given vertex set has $19+17=36$ edges. Recall that $K_n$ has $n\choose 2$ edges.